# Android Caching Framework

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, sharedpreferences, three20

In iOS Development there is three20 which takes care of all the caching (lists, webviews etc.) but is there something similar to this which takes care of the caching automatically?
Or would we have to do this all by ourselves?
If so what is the recommended way? Sqlite Database? Shared Prefs?

The thing is that we have over 10 different views (including lists, webviews and more lists) and we are loading data from the web. We want to show the cached data if it could not be loaded for a certain time.

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I wrote about a  generic way of caching, you might be interested: http://alnourpp.blogspot.no/2017/06/saving-data-in-multiple-data-stores-in.html I am thinking of extending this to a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` might have caching enabled, but it is not so with other views.You have to implement your own cache. However since SQLite is available on android, is pretty easy to implement a DB based cache. For example `DataCache.java` in [this project](https://bitbucket.org/zedvoid/aalp/src). Just make it a global singleton in Application class and use from anywhere in your code.